# Помогите придумать метод, который бы менял местами 2 View Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

Добрый день. Ломаю голову над тем, как реализовать метод
replace(View v1, View v2)
который должен поменять два View на фрагменте местами, которые лежат в корне constrait layout.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо поработать с классом [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html)

Нашел пример из похожего [вопроса на англ. стеке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442760/dynamically-changing-the-constraint-of-a-view-in-constraintlayout)

Но лучше вот эта [статья на русском](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/494-urok-183-constraintset-programmnaya-nastroyka-constraintlayout.html)

Логика следующая:
Создаёте `ConstaintSet set = new ConstraintSet()`

У него вызываете `.clone(myConstraintLayout)`
затем для конкретных вьюх вызываете

```
set.clear(view1, Constraint.PARAM)
```

очищаете привязку вьюхи к контреинту
и задаёте ей новый констреинт через

```
set.connect()
```

Затем подключаете анимацию `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myConstraintLayout);`

И под конец применяете все изменения к лэйауту

```
set.applyTo(myConstraintLayout);
```